# Prevent animation frame skipping in Android

Tags: android, performance

So on my emulator, especially when my computer is under heavy load, the animation tends to skip frames.

It doesn't happen often, but when it does it looks unsightly and I'm sure it could happen on real devices if they are slow.

Is there a way to make it wait for each frame to finish drawing instead of skipping them?

I'm using android.animation.* and android.view.animation.*

Comment: are you sure it would look better?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no.
Is there a way, for example, to make computer game not lagging if it's lagging on your machine? :)
This is just a natural way of things, and how system handles rendering.

You should not bother measuring any performance on emulator, especially while computer is under heavy load.
Instead, you need to make sure that your app doesn't occupy main thread with some long running tasks during animation